# Parallelizing for-loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I’m trying to parallelize a for loop that takes a list (hash_list), saves every element except the kth element and processes that second list.

```
from datasketch import lsh

class Hash():
    def __init__(self, hash_list):
        self.cnt = 0
        self.hash_list = hash_list

    def subhash(self, temp_hash_list):
        for item in temp_hash_list:
            lsh.insert(item)
        return lsh.query(self.hash_list[self.cnt])

    def main(self):
        for item in self.hash_list: #I want to parallelize this for loop
            temp_hash_list =self.hash_list[:self.cnt] + self.hash_list[self.cnt+1:]
            print self.subhash(temp_hash_list)
            self.cnt += 1

hash_list = […] 
h = Hash(hash_list)
h.main()
```

lsh is a library that has two methods: lsh.insert() and lsh.query(). It is used to compare similarities between  lists of strings. In this case, the list has been hashed to create the hash_list. lsh.insert() method is used to load hashed element into lsh while lsh.query() method is used to compare a particular element with the previously loaded elements.

The other examples in stackoverflow usually uses multiprocessing.Pool to parallelize operations performed on a list i.e. a single element at a time. In this case, I’m doing the opposite which is to perform operations on every element except the kth element. Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `Hash.main` trying to accomplish? Finding duplicates in the list of strings?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Yes, it's used to compare hashed list of strings. In this example, I'm printing out the results for manual comparison but it can also be used as an input to another function.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis To be exact it's not just finding duplicates, it's comparing two list of strings and returning the percentage of similarity. We can then set a threshold and filter out only those that meet or exceed that threshold, which is quite useful in certain applications. 

I still can't figure out how to proceed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.